# How do I add a runtime timeout to prevent java.net.SocketTimeoutException?

Tags: java, exception, timeout, runtime, jsoup

So I have a program that extracts business information from Yelp, and outputs it. Everything compiles, and runs for a while until it eventually hits java.net.SocketTimeoutException. I did some research on the issue and apparently it's an issue with the network, and the solution is to add a runtime timeout. Here's the thing, I have no clue how that's done, nor how to implement that into my code. Here's what I got:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class YelpScraper
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, Exception, RuntimeException
    {        
        //Variables
        String description;
        String location;
        int pages;
        int parseCount = 0;
        Document document;

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Perform a Search
        System.out.print("Enter a description: ");
        description = keyboard.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter a state: ");
        location = keyboard.nextLine();

        System.out.print("How many pages should we scan? ");
        pages = keyboard.nextInt();

        String descString = "find_desc=" + description.replace(' ', '+') + "&";
        String locString = "find_loc=" + location.replace(' ', '+') + "&";
        int number = 0;

        String url = "https://www.yelp.com/search?" + descString + locString + "start=" + number;
        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> address = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> phone = new ArrayList<String>();

        //Fetch Data From Yelp
        for (int i = 0 ; i <= pages ; i++)
        {

            document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

            Elements nameElements = document.select(".indexed-biz-name span");
            Elements addressElements = document.select(".secondary-attributes address");
            Elements phoneElements = document.select(".biz-phone");

            for (Element element : nameElements)
            {
                names.add(element.text());
            }

            for (Element element : addressElements)
            {
                address.add(element.text());
            }

            for (Element element : phoneElements)
            {
                phone.add(element.text());
            }

            for (int index = 0 ; index < 10 ; index++)
            {
                System.out.println("\nLead " + parseCount);
                System.out.println("Company Name: " + names.get(parseCount));
                System.out.println("Address: " + address.get(parseCount));
                System.out.println("Phone Number: " + phone.get(parseCount));

                parseCount = parseCount + 1;
            }

            number = number + 10;

        }
    }
}
```

What do I need to do to add a runtime timeout?

Comment: What has led you to the conclusion that you need a runtime timeout?

Answer (score 1):

You can always use timeout like in this doc:

https://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/load-document-from-url

like this:

```
document = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(3000).get();
```